# Getting an unexpected token error in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is my first time using react and I have somewhat limited experience with javascript in general. Trying to adapt a project I found on codepen for my project. The idea being creating a dynamic graded quiz that returns some output if a user selects the wrong answer.

This is what I have as my html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'second/css/app/quiz_control.css' %}">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="{% static 'second/js/app/quiz_control.js' %}" defer></script>
</head>
<main class="container">
  <section id="riots-to-renaissance">
  </section>
</main>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
const RawHTML = (props) => <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.html}}></span>;

class QuestionImage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.imgRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.imgRef.current && prevProps.img.src !== this.props.img.src) {
      this.imgRef.current.classList.add('fade-in');

      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.imgRef.current.classList.remove('fade-in');
        clearTimeout(timer);
      }, 1000)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <img ref={this.imgRef} className="img-fluid" src={this.props.img.src} alt={this.props.img.alt} />
    );
  }
}

const QuizProgress = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="progress">
      <p className="counter">
        <span>Question {props.currentQuestion+1} of {props.questionLength}</span>
      </p>
      <div className="progress-bar" style={{'width': ((props.currentQuestion+1) / props.questionLength) * 100 + '%'}}></div>
    </div>
  );
}

const Results = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="results fade-in">
      <h1>Your score: {((props.correct/props.questionLength) * 100).toFixed()}%</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={props.startOver}>Try again <i className="fas fa-redo"></i></button>
    </div>
  );
}

class Quiz extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.updateAnswer = this.updateAnswer.bind(this);
    this.checkAnswer = this.checkAnswer.bind(this);
    this.nextQuestion = this.nextQuestion.bind(this);
    this.getResults = this.getResults.bind(this);
    this.startOver = this.startOver.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      currentQuestion: 0,
      correct: 0,
      inProgress: true,
      questions: [{
        question: "<em>A Raisin in the Sun</em> was the first play by an African-American woman to be produced on Broadway. Who was the playwright?",
        options: [{
          option: "Lorraine Hansberry",
          correct: true
        }, {
          option: "Maya Angelou",
          correct: false
        }],
        img: {
          src: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/sites/default/files/dusable-to-obama_raisin-in-the-sun.jpg',
          alt: 'Characters in A Raisin in the Sun'
        },
        feedback: "Lorraine Hansberry's (1930–1965) play opened in 1959 to critical acclaim and was a huge success. The play is about a black family who faces racism when moving into an all-white suburb. The play is drawn from a similar experience in Hansberry’s early life.",
        moreUrl: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/dusable-to-obama/hansberrys-victory'
      }, {
        question: "The internationally famous Harlem Globetrotters basketball team started with players from which Chicago High School?",
        options: [{
          option: "Wendell Phillips High School",
          correct: true
        }, {
          option: "DuSable High School",
          correct: false
        }],
        img: {
          src: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/sites/default/files/dusable/riots_renaissance_thumb_5.jpg',
          alt: 'A Harlem Globetrotter holding a basketball in each hand'
        },
        feedback: "The athletes who would become Harlem Globetrotters first played together as students at Wendell Phillips High School on the south side of Chicago. Later, they played as a team under the banner of the South Side's Giles Post of the American Legion and then as the Savoy Big Five before taking on their current name. The team was based in Chicago for 50 years, from 1926 through 1976.",
        moreUrl: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/dusable-to-obama/harlem-globetrotters'
      }, {
        question: "What Chicagoan is known as the father of Gospel Music?",
        options: [{
          option: "Thomas A. Dorsey",
          correct: true
        }, {
          option: "Langston Hughes",
          correct: false
        }],
        img: {
          src: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/sites/default/files/dusable-to-obama_thomas-dorsey.jpg',
          alt: 'Thomas Andrew Dorsey'
        },
        feedback: "Some.",
        moreUrl: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/dusable-to-obama/dorseys-gospel'
      }, {
        question: "Which of these African-American women ran for the office of president of the United States?",
        options: [{
          option: "All of the above",
          correct: true
        }, {
          option: "None of the above",
          correct: false
        }],
        img: {
          src: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/sites/default/files/dusable/achieving_dream_thumb_9.jpg',
          alt: 'Carol Moseley-Braun'
        },
        feedback: "more text.\"",
        moreUrl: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/dusable-to-obama/carol-moseley-braun'
      }, {
        question: "Who was Oscar Stanton De Priest?",
        options: [{
          option: "The first Catholic priest in Chicago",
          correct: false
        }, {
          option: "A United States congressman",
          correct: true
        }],
        img: {
          src: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/sites/default/files/dusable-to-obama_oscar-stanton-de-priest.jpg',
          alt: 'Oscar Stanton De Priest'
        },
        feedback: "Text again.",
        moreUrl: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/dusable-to-obama/carol-moseley-braun'
      }, {
        question: "What musical artist was part of Chicago's Black Renaissance?",
        options: [{
          option: "Louis Armstrong",
          correct: false
        }, {
          option: "Nat \"King\" Cole",
          correct: true
        }, {
          option: "Curtis Mayfield",
          correct: false
        }],
        img: {
          src: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/sites/default/files/dusable-to-obama_nat-king-cole.jpg',
          alt: 'Nat King Cole'
        },
        feedback: "Long text.",
        moreUrl: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/dusable-to-obama/dorseys-gospel'
      }, {
        question: "Gwendolyn Brooks was:",
        options: [{
          option: "the first black woman to win a Pulitzer Prize in poetry.",
          correct: false
        }, {
          option: "all of the above",
          correct: true
        }],
        img: {
          src: 'https://interactive.wttw.com/sites/default/files/dusable-to-obama_gwendolyn-brooks.jpg',
          alt: 'Gwendolyn Brooks'
        },
        feedback: "Gwendolyn Brooks (1917–2000) is a jewel in Chicago’s literary history. She was a writer best known for her poetry describing life in the South Side community in which she lived."
      }]
    }
  }

  updateAnswer(e) {
    //record whether the question was answered correctly
    let answerValue = e.target.value;

    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      let stateToUpdate = prevState.questions;
      //convert boolean string to boolean with JSON.parse()
      stateToUpdate[prevState.currentQuestion].answerCorrect = JSON.parse(answerValue);

      return {questions: stateToUpdate};
    });
  }

  checkAnswer(e) {
    //display to the user whether their answer is correct
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      let stateToUpdate = prevState.questions;
      stateToUpdate[prevState.currentQuestion].checked = true;

      return {questions: stateToUpdate};
    });
  }

  nextQuestion(e) {
    //advance to the next question
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      let stateToUpdate = prevState.currentQuestion;

      return {currentQuestion: stateToUpdate+1};
    }, () => {
      this.radioRef.current.reset();
    });
  }

  getResults() {
    //loop through questions and calculate the number right
    let correct = this.state.correct;

    this.state.questions.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (item.answerCorrect) {
        ++correct;
      }

      if (index === (this.state.questions.length-1)) {
        this.setState({
          correct: correct,
          inProgress: false
        });
      }
    });
  }

  startOver() {
    //reset form and state back to its original value
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      let questionsToUpdate = prevState.questions;

      questionsToUpdate.forEach(item => {
        //clear answers from previous state
        delete item.answerCorrect;
        delete item.checked;
      });

      return {
        inProgress: true,
        correct: 0,
        currentQuestion: 0,
        questions: questionsToUpdate
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //since we're re-using the same form across questions,
    //create a ref to it so we can clear its state after a question is answered
    this.radioRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.inProgress) {
      return (
        <section className="quiz">
          <Results correct={this.state.correct} questionLength={this.state.questions.length} startOver={this.startOver} />
        </section>
      );
    }

    return (
      <section className="quiz fade-in" aria-live="polite">
        <QuizProgress currentQuestion={this.state.currentQuestion} questionLength={this.state.questions.length} />
        <div className="question-container">
          {this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].img.src &&
            <QuestionImage img={this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].img} />
          }
          <p className="question"><RawHTML html={this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].question} /></p>

          <form ref={this.radioRef}>
            {this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].options.map((item, index) => {
              return <div key={index}
                      className={"option" + (this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].checked && !item.correct ? ' dim' : '') + (this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].checked && item.correct ? ' correct' : '')}>
                      <input id={"radio-"+index} onClick={this.updateAnswer} type="radio" name="option" value={item.correct}
                          disabled={this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].checked} />
                        <label htmlFor={"radio-"+index}><RawHTML html={item.option}/></label>
                    </div>
              })}
          </form>

          <div className="bottom">
            {this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].feedback && this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].checked
              && <div className="fade-in">
                <p>
                  <RawHTML html={this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].feedback} />
                  {this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].moreUrl &&
                    <React.Fragment>
                       &nbsp;<a target="_blank" href={this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].moreUrl}>Learn more</a>.
                    </React.Fragment>
                  }
                </p>
              </div>
            }

            {!this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].checked &&
               <button type="button" onClick={this.checkAnswer}
               disabled={!('answerCorrect' in this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion])}>Check answer</button>
             }

            {(this.state.currentQuestion+1) < this.state.questions.length && this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].checked &&
              <button className="fade-in next" type="button" onClick={this.nextQuestion}>Next <i className="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
            }
          </div>

          {(this.state.currentQuestion+1) === this.state.questions.length && this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].checked &&
            <button type="button" className="get-results pulse" onClick={this.getResults}>Get Results</button>
          }
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<Quiz />, document.getElementById('riots-to-renaissance'));
})
```

and css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

@green: #36ad3b;
@red: #ff1100;
@yellow: #f3c000;
@blue: #1d77cc;

@sans: "Open Sans", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;

@keyframes roll-in {
  0% {
    top: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

.pulse {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
}

.fade-in {
  animation: fade .75s ease;
}

.quiz {
  margin: 2em auto;
  min-height: 40vh;
  font-size: 16px;

  .progress {
    position: relative;
    transition: width .4s ease;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    background: rgb(181, 181, 181);
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    font-family: @sans;

    .progress-bar {
      background-color: #1d77cc;
    }

    .counter {
      position: absolute;
      right: 5px;
      top: 0;
      font-weight: normal;
      color: #fff;
      height: 100%;
      font-family: @sans;
      font-size:1.25em;
      margin: auto .5em;
      letter-spacing:.025em;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }
  }

  form {
    width:90%;
    margin:1.5em auto;
  }

  .img-fluid {
    margin: 2em auto;
    max-width: 360px;
    display: block;
  }

  .question {
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:1.35;
    margin-bottom:.75em;
  }

  .option {
    margin-bottom: .25em;
    transition: all .25s ease;
    font-size: .9em;
  }

  button {
    padding: .75em;
    font-family: @sans;
    background-color: #1d77cc;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: .25s all;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;

    i {
      margin-left: .15em;
    }

    &:disabled {
      opacity: .5;
    }
  }

  //custom radio controls
  input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;

      & + label {
      position: relative;
      font-weight: normal;
      padding-left: 28px;
      cursor: pointer;
      line-height: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
      color: #666;

      &::before {
        text-align: center;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-radius: 100%;
        background: #fff;
      }

      &::after {
        content: '';
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        background-color: #222;
        position: absolute;
        top: 4px;
        left: 4px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
      }
    }
  }

  .dim, .correct {
    input[type="radio"] + label::before {
      border: 0;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      animation: .25s roll-in ease;
    }

    input[type="radio"] + label::after {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  .correct input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    content: '\f00C';
    font-family: "FontAwesome"!important;
    color: @green;
  }

  .dim input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    content: '\f00d';
    font-family: "FontAwesome"!important;
    color: @red;
  }

  input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  //end custom radio controls

  .dim {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  .bottom {
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;

    div {
      flex: 1 1 70%;
      font-size: .9em;
    }

    .next {
      flex: 0 1 10%;
      margin-left: 3em;
    }

    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      div, .next {
        flex-basis: 100%;
      }

      .next {
        margin-left: 0;
      }
    }
  }

  .get-results {
    display: block;
    margin: 2em auto;
  }

  .results {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 40vh;

    h1 {
      font-family: @sans;
    }

    button {
      margin-top: 1em;
    }
  }
}
```

When I check my browser console, I get the error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Comment: you should not use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. And I guess that you have not configured `babel` to make use of `JSX`. This should be the reason for your parser not to be able to parse the following line of code: `const RawHTML = (props) => <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.html}}></span>;`

Comment: @messerbill mind adding this as an answer with a bit more elaboration?

Comment: `JSX` is not native javascript code. To get this running you need to configure `babel` to do so. https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html